# how to stop selenium chromedriver from logging to the screen

Tags: cucumber, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

How do I stop selenium chromedriver from logging errors to the screen?

I am running some cucumber tests and Im using capybara & the selenium chromedriver to drive the tests. 
In the last few weeks ive noticed that the Chromedriver has started logging its error messages to the screen. My tests still run fine but the errors are clogging up the output.

This is the output below:

```
Started ChromeDriver
port=9515
version=23.0.1240.0
log=C:\Gitrepos\Base Tests\chromedriver.log
[8244:5080:1115/151428:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(91)] Can't retrieve a valid WinSAT assessment.
    Given I Select "Customer" from the "Search" gadget
    And I enter "Test Customer" for "Customer Name"
    And click "Search"
    And Select "Manage Customer" from the "Main Menu" drop down
```

The solution would be to remove the following line from the output or possibly to fix the error.
**[8244:5080:1115/151428:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(91)] Can't retrieve a valid WinSAT 
assessment.**

I upgraded the driver to fix a different error but I ended up getting this error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to start the Chromedriver using a redirect of STDERR, e.g.

chromedriver.exe 2>c:\temp\err.log

Comment: That is a good solution but I cant get it to work in this case because I dont know where chromedriver.exe is getting called.
I'll have a look around the selenium-driver code to see if I can find where its called.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, here is what suppressed all those chrome messages (chrome prints a few sorts.. ):

> ```
>     ChromeOptions chromeOptions = setupChromeOptions();
>     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "\\path\\chromedriver.log");
>     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\path\\chromedriver.exe");
>     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.args", "--disable-logging");
>     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
>     driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
> ```

This works for me with the following config

> ```
>   selenium-chrome-driver-2.48.2.jar
>   chromedriver 2.20
>   selenium-java-2.48.2.jar
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This was the only thing that worked:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
```