# How to hide Chromedriver console message/output

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

I am using ChromeDriver in C# code console app, everything works well as I expect. But I need to hide the messages/logs from the chrome driver. Used below code. Still seeing the messages like:

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578737
>   (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e) on port 51929
>
> Only local connections are allowed.
>
> DevTools listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:51932/devtools/browser/09ed1c7f-c33a-4f76-990b-943c6837d8d8

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
chromeDriverService.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true; 
options.AddArgument("headless");
options.AddArgument("--silent");
options.AddArgument("log-level=3");
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),options);
```

I did suppress the logs by adding "options.AddArgument("log-level=3");". I am trying to avoid seeing below in my console, I need to suppress these messages too:

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578737
>   (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e) on port 51929
>
> Only local connections are allowed.
>
> DevTools listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:51932/devtools/browser/09ed1c7f-c33a-4f76-990b-943c6837d8d8"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to stop selenium chromedriver from logging to the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400765/how-to-stop-selenium-chromedriver-from-logging-to-the-screen)

Comment: @Hirasawa, thanks but  the solution will just log the console error of different level into a file. It just take care of the log but not the messages which I mentioned.

Comment: I made mistake, missed to add the ChromeDriverService like below code. Which solves my issue
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService ,options);

Got the help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417581/selenium-chromedriver-how-to-disable-the-messagedevtools-on-ws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the chromeDriverService in the ChromeDriver constructor:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);
```